Python convert list of tuples into dataframe
I have a variable that stores a single list of tuples.
It looks like this:
builddict =  [
    ('MfgPartNumber', 'ITEM NUMBER'), 
    ('ShortDescription', 'ITEM DESCRIPTION'), 
    ('StdPk', 'PACKAGE QTY'), 
    ('ListPrice', 'LIST PRICE'), 
    ('Cost', 'NET PRICE APRIL 2024')
]

It is dynamically created based on a loop, so the values will vary by output.
I would like to take that list and build a dataframe from it with the first item as the column name, and the second item and the corresponding row.
For Example:
| MfgParNumber | ShortDescription   | StdPk |
| ------------ | ------------------- |----- |
| ITEM NUMBER  | ITEM DESCRIPTION   |PACKAGE QTY|  etc...

I tried this, but can't figure out how to apply the column names to it:
DictCols = list(zip(*builddict))[0]
DictData = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*builddict))[1]).T
print(DictData)


Does this answer your question? Constructing DataFrame from values in variables yields "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

"I tried this, but can't figure out how to apply the column names to it:" What happens when you try that, and how is that different from what you want?

To be clear: you want the result DataFrame to only ever have one row of data (and a header)? Exactly what is the use of this result?

Think about how you'd want the data to be structured to create the DataFrame you want normally, then do all the data rearrangement first.

You could convert the tuple to a list of dicts by:
build_dict = [{k: v for k, v in builddict}]

and then create a dataframe from this dict
build_df = pd.DataFrame(build_dict)

That should work for a variable length list of tuples.

For the data row, you need to put it in another list. Then pass the list of column names as the columns argument.
cols, data = zip(*builddict)
df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=cols)

